# Rbokeh error in Jupyter: "No such file or directory"

Tags: r, jupyter, rbokeh

I'm having some problems using Rbokeh in Jupyter with R (all other packages work fine). Essentially, when I try to run the Rbokeh plot, I get this scary looking error message:

```
Warning message in read.dcf(file.path(p, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Version")):
“cannot open compressed file '~/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rbokeh/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'”Warning message in read.dcf(file.path(p, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Version")):
“cannot open compressed file '~/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rbokeh/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'”
```

I've installed the R package and R essentials from Anaconda. There, they are showing as installed, however when I look for them in the file paths above I can't see them. Am I missing something obvious? My code looks like this.

```
library(readxl)
library(rbokeh)

df <- read_xlsx("~/df.xlsx")

p <- figure() %>%
ly_points(x, y, data = df)
p
```

I am very new to Anaconda and a little intimidated. If someone can help it would be much appreciated!